# Windows 7 bluetooth headset as audio sink issues

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I can't keep my headset up as an audio sink in Windows 7.  After any kind of disconnect (eg, power down the headset to recharge it), only deleting and re-pairing the device will product audio.

The Toshiba bluetooth device manager shows it as paired and the sound control panel shows it as a sink with audio being dumped there... so why no audio on the headset itself without the re-pair?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas.  1.  Goto devices and printers then right click on the device select Audio Sink and Handsfree Telephony then Apply and close. 
2.  Still in Devices double left click and then see if you can select music etc and select each service listed

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: The Toshiba BT manager hijacks BT devices from the Windows device manager control panel.  It automatically assigns the device to those device and service classes for me.